# Run script on remote server securely

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a single script on a remote server once a user has changed a setting via my web interface. I only want to run 1 specific file, I know I can do a simple bash script to do this.

My issue is security, if somehow my web server was compromised they could do other things aside from running that script on the remote server.

Is there a was to lock down the user for the remote session so it can only run that specific file? Or another way I've not thought of?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying command in the authorized_keys file by adding something like

```
command="/opt/script.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty $public_key
```

On the client side you would simply use

```
ssh $remoteserver '/opt/script.sh'
```

in your script.